# How to change TextBox's Background color for the "Not selected state"?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, textbox, windows-phone-8.1, passwordbox

I can change the background color for my `TextBox` and `PasswordBox` in the `XAML` in my Windows Phone 8.1 project. But I noticed that when the `TextBox` and `PasswordBox` is in the "not selected state" (when I'm not typing in it) it has a light gray color.

Is there a way to change the light gray color to be white?

[image: Here the TextBox is unselected][image: Here the TextBox is selected]

Comment: You'll either want to override the brush that it's set to for that state in the style template. Or do it directly to the style template(s) for those controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In App resources, override the following the properties:

```
<x:Double x:Key="TextControlBackgroundThemeOpacity">1.0</x:Double>
<x:Double x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeOpacity">1.0</x:Double>
```